# How to use multiple images in ReactJS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, bundle, css-sprites

I have a ReactJS application. I have 100 images(icons) of country flags. I need to use them in my application. I have 2 ways to do so, want to know best way to do so such that -
1) I only have to make 1 hhtp call to get the images
2) It is the most optimum way to handle this scenario.

Method 1 - I can sprite all the 100 images. And then make 1 http call to get the image and make use of background positions to get correct image.
In this method I wanted to know if
a) If using CSS Sprites is the modern way of doing so? Any better way?
b) If using CSS sprites, any tool to create a Sprite image and get the correct position values?

Method 2 - In my project, currently all images are inside a /src/images folder. If I put the 100 images inside this folder, it will make 100 http calls. Correct me if I am wrong. Can I put them inside /public/images folder so that the images are bundled and not excess http call is to be made? (If I reference any image file in public folder I get the error - 'Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.') Anyway, where do you usually place images, inside /src/images or /public/images? What are the advantages in either?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option. Depending on the tooling, you can use Webpack or other bundlers to compress (gzip or Brotli compression).

You can optimize images to make sure they are not overly large and properly formatted, then compress and serve from a reverse proxy server.

To further boost performance, you can defer off-screen assets so that the images that you need are loaded as they are needed which lowers the initial fetch size.

Lastly, you can use in-memory caching, S3 (or other cloud storage), and a Content Delivery Network (like Cloudforce, Akkimai, and others), to store images in the cloud in close proximity to the user. CDNs are optimized to deliver such static assets and might be something to consider incorporating.

Answer (score 0):

With such a heavy usage of images, I would suggest that you **LazyLoad** the images with option 2.

Consider a case where you have 100 products on your web page. If you request all the 100 product images at the same time and at the very beginning, it would slow down the load time. With lazy loading, we would only load, let’s say, 30 images that are visible to the user initially. Then, when the user starts scrolling down the page, we will keep loading more images. This would help improve the initial load time and the user experience. There will be cases where the user doesn’t scroll down the entire page and hence some images would not get loaded at all. Thus, you also end up saving on bandwidth costs for image delivery.

Since you are using reactjs, there are many packages available for this. Here I'll suggest one of them but feel free to explore more: [React-Lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload)

You can even deliver the images through some **CDN** to further fasten the loading. Also, **resizing** them to actual needed size is a good way. Moreover you can also use **JPG encoded at 80-90 quality** as it won't make much of a difference in image quality, but reduce the file size dramatically.